# Schema.org - Hierarchical or loose layout?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I am tagging the product pages of a webshop using Schema.org. So far, I have used a hierarchical structure where the `body` tag is marked as `ItemPage`. Then I can use the property `breadcrumb` on `ItemPage` for my breadcrumbs, and another property `mainEntity` which is a `Product`. This does not give any warnings in the [Structured Data testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) - the hierarchy is displayed here the way I intended.

But I wonder if Google would pick up my `Product`/`Offer` markup easier if it wasn't bundled within an `ItemPage`. That is, should I skip `ItemPage` and just have the `Product` as a loose elements, along with breadcrumbs, and other ItemLists?

Which is better?

**Example of my hierarchical layout:**

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
    <div>Some other stuff...</div>
    <ol itemprop="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
            <a href="/a" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">A</span></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
            <a href="/b" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">B</span></a>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <img src="/image.jpg" itemprop="image">
        <h1 itemprop="name">My Product</h1>
        <div itemprop="description">Example text</div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <meta itemprop="price" content="129">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="SEK">
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
            <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Example of loose tagging:**
(The BreadcrumbList and the Product are not "itemprop" of anything)

```html
<body>
    <div>Some other stuff...</div>
    <ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
            <a href="/a" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">A</span></a>
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
            <a href="/b" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">B</span></a>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <img src="/image.jpg" itemprop="image">
        <h1 itemprop="name">My Product</h1>
        <div itemprop="description">Example text</div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <meta itemprop="price" content="129">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="SEK">
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
            <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of the hierarchical layout is very close to the suggested usage of the `mainEntity` property suggested by the official protocol documentation:

As [mainEntity](https://schema.org/mainEntity) definition "*indicates the primary entity described in some page*", **this is a perfect fit for your case**, so my suggestion is that you choose this well structured code, Google should understand it perfectly.

This is the relevant code for this example used in *schema.org* main property:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
...
<div itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <a href="category/books.html">Books</a> >
  <a href="category/books-literature.html">Literature & Fiction</a> >
  <a href="category/books-classics">Classics</a>
</div>
<div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
<img itemprop="image" src="catcher-in-the-rye-book-cover.jpg"
     alt="cover art: red horse, city in background"/>
<span itemprop="name">The Catcher in the Rye</span> -
 <link itemprop="bookFormat" href="http://schema.org/Paperback">Mass Market Paperback
by <a itemprop="author" href="/author/jd_salinger.html">J.D. Salinger</a>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
  <span itemprop="reviewCount">3077</span> reviews
</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  Price: $<span itemprop="price">6.99</span>
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">In Stock
</div>
Product details
<span itemprop="numberOfPages">224</span> pages
Publisher: <span itemprop="publisher">Little, Brown, and Company</span> -
 <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="1991-05-01">May 1, 1991
Language: <span itemprop="inLanguage">English</span>
ISBN-10: <span itemprop="isbn">0316769487</span>
</div>
...
</body>
```

The above example and yours, both are being fully processed by https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool with very similar results.

Comment: Thanks! I would agree, but Google has not indexed the markup (for example, no aggretated rating is shown) on a website I tested this on, even though the code has been there about 3 months now. Oh well!

Comment: Did you send the webpage URL to Google to be sure it crawls it again?

Comment: Yes, I've submitted the sitemap and Google is crawling pages every day, but for some reason the structured data is not picked up the way I had hoped. I can see that Google has found many ItemPage objects in Search Console, but no Product/Offer objects.

Comment: By experimenting I got much better results when using only 1 top-level object - in my case, the ItemPage. Previously I had an ItemPage with a Product as mainEntity, but also a couple of "loose" ItemLists. This caused Google to see 3 top-level objects and I guess they got confused. When reducing the markup and using only ItemPage -> Product -> Offer etc the products got indexed right away.

Comment: You mean removing the mainEntity?

Comment: No, I kept mainEntity, so that the mainEntity of ItemPage is a Product. I removed a few ItemLists since they couldn't be connected to the ItemPage in a similar hieararchical way. The result was that the ItemPage became the lone top-level object and this seemed to work much better.